# How to sign an agent certificate in puppet?

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

I am using `puppet` 7.15.0 and when I try to `puppet agent -vt`, I get the below meesage:

> Couldn't fetch certificate from CA server; you might still need to sign this agent's certificate (my-vm.zhuva2dr5tmurl44jnenpmoh1f.px.internal.cloudapp.net).
> Exiting now because the waitforcert setting is set to 0

Can someone help me how can I sign this cert?

Answer (score 1):

The `puppet cert sign` command on the Puppet master exists for exactly that purpose.